# How to get adjusted dependent variable

Tags: r, statistics

I am working on adjusting urine sodium by urine creatinine and age in order to use the adjusted variable in further analysis.

How do I create a new variable with the adjusted version of the data?? Do I divide NA24 by creatinine and age? Do I multiply them? Please help.

I ran a linear model as follows, but not sure what to do with the information:

```
Call:
lm(formula = PRENA24 ~ PRECR24mmol * PREALD, data = c1.3)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-228.439  -43.024   -5.215   37.790  274.414 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        66.84482   29.60684   2.258  0.02423 *  
PRECR24mmol         7.00565    2.10989   3.320  0.00094 ***
PREALD             -0.66555    0.60912  -1.093  0.27488    
PRECR24mmol:PREALD  0.06335    0.04392   1.442  0.14962    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 65.94 on 798 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2963,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2937 
F-statistic:   112 on 3 and 798 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I need to adjust the PRENA24 value and I want to make a new column with these values (i.e. PRENA24.ADJ).

I know the following is incorrect, but I am not sure what else to do with the information from the linear model. The post lab data is separated by treatment type as well.

```
c1 <- c1.3 %>%
  mutate(PRENA24.ADJ = (PRENA24-66.84482+(7.00565*PRECR24mmol)+(-0.66555*PREALD)))
c2 <- c1 %>%
  mutate(NA24.ADJ = (NA24-24.59443+(10.54905*CR24mmol)+(0.58894*ALD)))
```